# Regular Expression to surround date with quotation marks

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of data all in the same format which I need to analyse in Weka.

I need to surround the date/time values with quotation marks "" but can't work out a regular expression to complete it..

I need to change a row from this:

```
1028,NULL,1,21,7,AD9,06A,60136859,NULL,1,4,3,2012-02-21 10:05:00.100,2012-02-21 10:05:23.170
```

to a row like this:

```
1027,NULL,1,21,7,AD9,06A,60136859,NULL,1,5,4,"2012-02-21 10:03:53.643","2012-02-21 10:04:29.787"
```

where the date/time values are surrounded by quotation marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work in notepad++ as long as your datetime values are always fully formatted.

```
Find what: (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})
Replace with: "\1"
```

This works because of backreferences. Everything that is captured within parenthesis is stored as a backreference. You access backreferences by typing `\number` where number correlates to the position of parenthesis in the regex. So since we are only using one pair of parenthesis, want backreference 1, and we use `\1`.

So you find the `entire date` and it gets stored in `\1` because of the parenthesis in your regex. Then you replace the `entire date` with `"entire date"` aka `"\1"`.